# Use docker for day to day development with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I am a Ruby/Rails developer. In order to work on different projects and with different Ruby versions, I use Docker. I run some commands very, very frequently. I need to do it fast and to have a fast execution time. Without Docker, I like to use Spring because I save a few seconds each time (8 to 20 seconds on my current project). I found a way to still use it with Docker, I run a bash session, with docker-compose run web bash, and I run my command inside. It works but there is a few drawbacks. I have to have a Tmux panel opened continuously. It does not work with some vim plugins when I need to execute a command and get the result.

I can exec command on a runner container by doing docker exec -it  bin/rspec. It works but it shutdown spring each time.

I can also install all my favorite tools (vim, tmux, zsh, etc.) inside my development containers but I don't think it's a good practice.

I'm looking for a solution as similar as possible than running command inside my local machine. I think it's possible to create a shortcut like `de my_command`, for docker exec.

Do you have solution? Do you have the same problems? Is it a good practice to use docker for a day to day development?

Comment: What issue did you have with using a Ruby version manager? I mean, yes, using containers for a consistent environment is fine, but it's not clear to me what specific issue you faced that required a container, e.g., DB versions/implementations etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I like to keep my machine clean. I don't need to install capybara-webkit, poltergeist, etc. Furthermore, it's very useful to share Dockerfile between collaborators.

Comment: So you already think it's a good idea (which is an opinion based question, hence OT for SO :) Requests for libraries and tools are also OT.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry, but I don't know what is OT.... I'm not use that is a good idea but I want to find more useful command.

Comment: @davenewton, many questions about docker are OT on SO but SO still the most popular platform to ask them.

Comment: @Dongui You can mount the volume containing the code base. If you are using `docker-compose`, you could run `docker-compose run web <All commands (rake & rails)>`. You can use your editor in the host machine. All  commands will be fired in the `docker-machine` and keep your local machine clean from all the libraries.

Comment: @anoop it will not resolve my problem with background processes. With `run` all processes are stopped each time.

Comment: @Dougui have you tried adding a -d option?

Comment: @anoop, -d is for detach. I don't see the relation with the problem.

Comment: @Dougui sorry if I'm mistaken but docker run -d is for long running processes. Refer this link https://labs.ctl.io/long-running-processes-in-docker/

Comment: @anoop, I see what you mean. I need to have a background process in the same  container where I run my other commands.